# Does PL/SQL have an intrinsic function to return a value of n when x is less than y?

Tags: plsql

I was thinking that there had to be a function that would act as a threshold, so that I didn't need to add a bunch of if-then-elses to my code.

I wrote a UDF to do what I need but if anyone knows of a PL/SQL function or code where I can say something like;

```
X := APPLY_THRESHOLD(LASTNAME_SCORE,PATIENT_LASTNAME_THRESHOLD,0);
```

Where X would either be the lastname_score, or 0, depending on whether it is greater than or equal to patient_last_name_threshold. The function I wrote is;

```
  FUNCTION APPLY_THRESHOLD(IN_VALUE NUMBER,IN_THRESHOLD NUMBER, IN_FLOOR NUMBER) RETURN NUMBER DETERMINISTIC AS

  BEGIN
    IF IN_VALUE < IN_THRESHOLD
    THEN
      RETURN IN_FLOOR;
    ELSE
      RETURN IN_VALUE;
    END IF;
  END APPLY_THRESHOLD;
```

But if there is something built in to the language it would probably be faster.

Comment: As there's no IIF() in PL/SQL, you have to use DECODE or CASE. Or IF as you do already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
select decode(sign(IN_VALUE - IN_THRESHOLD), -1, IN_FLOOR, IN_VALUE) 
into x from dual;
```

[sign( number ) Function](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/sign.php)

if `number < 0` it will return `-1`, if `number = 0` then `0` else `1`

Comment: That works, and I'll give you credit but I'll stay with my own solution as it looks cleaner, and I am not sure which would incur more overhead.